# Invalid Constant Value using variable as parameter

Tags: dart, flutter

```dart
var textSize = 10.0;
// or
double textSize = 10.0;
```

into `Text` Widget of Flutter

```dart
child: const Text('Calculate Client Fees',
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize),)
```

Here it is giving error

> Invalid Constant Value

Do we have to compulsory use `const` value? Why can not we use `var` or `double`?

Answer (score 335, accepted):

You are declaring your `Text` widget as a `const`, which requires all of its children to be `const` as well. If you want to fix this, you should not use a `const` `Text` widget in this case as you want to pass a non-const variable.

The reason for this is that Flutter uses the `const` keyword as an idicator for a widget to **never** rebuild as it will get evaluated at compile time and *only once*. Hence, every part of it has to be constant as well.

```dart
double textSize = 10.04;
// ...
child: Text('Calculate Client Fees', style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize))
```

Read more about it [in this article](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html).

Comment: Quite literally I have spent about a day on this, and have explored literally EVERY other possibility to get this to work.  Turns out I simply had the parent widget set to a constant.  You sir are a lifesaver.

Answer (score 48):

Don't use the **const** keyword if you are not using fixed values.
For example, in the case of `Text`, if its string is constant like `Text("something here")` then we should use the `const` but if the string of `Text` is dynamic then don't use const before `Text` widget.
`const Text("something")` and `Text(anyVariabale)`
The same is the case for all widgets.

Comment: A little explanation and code would definitely help.

Comment: basically you need to remove the `const`  before the Text widget, since the value is not yet set (or might change) at compile time

Comment: A little explanation and code IN THE ANSWER ITSELF would definitely help. ;) I got it, though! But it's a good general practice. Thousands of people will read this answer over the years...... ;D

Answer (score 13):

As [@creativecreatorormaybenot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6509751) said you are using `const Text()` which is why you have to have a `const` value there. 
You can either use

```
const double textSize = 10.0;
```

or

```
const textSize = 10.0;
```

---

Just like this case.

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(value), // this value has to be a `const` because our padding: is marked const
  child: Text("HI there"),
);


Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10), // any double value
  child: Text("HI there"),
);
```

Answer (score 12):

In dart when you pass something as a parameter in a const constructor, the compiler makes sure that the value set as default is not changed during the execution of the code.

Hence, the Invalid constant value warning.

To resolve this issue you should remove the const keyword from the in front of the Text.

Answer (score 8):

```dart
child: const Text('Calculate Client Fees',
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize),)
```

should be:

```dart
child: Text('Calculate Client Fees',
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize),)
```

Answer (score 6):

You should remove the keywords **const**

When it is used, it put the widget into the cache.

And you can't wait for a value into your widget and put the widget again as a constance. When you want to do that, you should not put your widget constant.

So do that:

```
double textSize = 10.0;
child: Text('Calculate Client Fees', style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize),)
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes this can be tricky because the `Text` widget might not be the one which is `const` (where the error is displayed), but maybe its parent widget is `const` or the parent of that parent widget, etc. In that case it could be surprising and not immediate to spot the solution. For example:

```
      const PrefLabel(
        title: Text(
          preferenceOptionTitle,
          style: Get.textTheme.headline5!,
          maxLines: 3,
        ),
        subtitle: Text(preferenceOptionDescription),
      ),
```

In this case the `Text` is not marked with `const` because the `PrefLabel` is already `const`. The corrected one which passes linting: `const` is moved to the subtitle

```
      PrefLabel(
        title: Text(
          preferenceOptionTitle,
          style: Get.textTheme.headline5!,
          maxLines: 3,
        ),
        subtitle: const Text(preferenceOptionDescription),
      ),
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use the `var` or `double textSize = 10.0;` then the text widget must not be a const. remove the `const` before the Text()

```
  child: Text('Calculate Client Fees', style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize),)
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to Just remove the `const` keyword.
replace with:

```
child: const Text('Calculate Client Fees',
               style: TextStyle(fontSize: textSize),)
```